# Getting unhandled exception when reader is executed

Tags: vb.net, oledb

help please i'm stuck  the code seems to be fine but im getting unhandeled exception

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Media
Public Class login
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
    Dim x As Integer = 0


    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Stock.mdb; Persist Security Info=True")
    Dim com As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [login] WHERE [unameField] = username AND [pwdField] = password", con)

    Dim usrparm As New OleDbParameter("username", Me.UsernameTextBox.Text)
    Dim pwdparm As New OleDbParameter("password", Me.PasswordTextBox.Text)

    com.Parameters.Add(usrparm)
    com.Parameters.Add(pwdparm)

    com.Connection.Open()
```

*getting error on execute reader unhandeled exception*

```
    Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = com.ExecuteReader()

    If reader.HasRows Then
        adminpanel.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox("Invalid credentials", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Error")
        x = x + 1
    End If
    com.Connection.Close()

    If x > 3 Then
        MsgBox("You don't have access to the software please cotact administrator", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Uauthorised access")
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Cancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Cancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please help yourself: ***what exception do you get?***

Comment: just to add what @JohnSaunders rightfully said, I don't see your SQL Statement being parameterized...

Comment: FYI, if you're getting unhandled exceptions, then your code is not fine.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: unhandled exceptions are better than empty `Catch` blocks.

Comment: @Tim: I haven't suggested otherwise. I almost never use empty catch blocks, and am more likely to remove try/catch statements from code than to add them.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: not you but maybe somebody else could think that an unhandled exception could be bad and therefore an `Catch` block would be better even if it's empty.

Comment: @Tim: I punish people like that on a regular basis. I usually make them stand in a corner, or write on the chalkboard: "I will not hide exceptions. I will not hide exceptions..."

Comment: @user3055332: do you know what an exception is? You say you got an unandled exception. Please tell us what you saw.

Answer (score 0):

If i remember correctly the syntax for `OleDbParamaters` in Access requires a `@` before the parameter:

```
Dim com As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [login] WHERE [unameField] = @username AND [pwdField] = @password", con)

Dim usrparm As New OleDbParameter("@username", Me.UsernameTextBox.Text)
Dim pwdparm As New OleDbParameter("@password", Me.PasswordTextBox.Text)
```

Comment: @user3055332: tell us what exception you're getting.

Comment: @user3055332: You have used all three lines above since every line contains modifications? Is the exception the same or is it different now?

Comment: and the exception is same

Answer (score 0):

This works if your database name and column names match the SELECT exactly. The bad thing here is that parameters are not named and hence the order of adding them to the collection is significant.

```
   Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=Stock.MDB; Persist Security Info=True")  'I use ACCDB
        Dim com As New OleDbCommand("SELECT [ID] FROM [login] WHERE ( [unameField] = ? AND [pwdField] = ?); ", con)
        com.Parameters.Clear()
        Dim parm1 As OleDb.OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter()
        Dim parm2 As OleDb.OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter()
        com.Parameters.Add(parm1)
        com.Parameters.Add(parm2)
        parm1.Value = Me.UsernameTextBox.Text
        parm2.Value = Me.PasswordTextBox.Text
        com.Connection.Open()
... the rest of your code goes here
```

I suggest you consult a resource on recent versions of ADO.NET so that you could construct better code than this. Also the user of try/catch and isolating data access code from form code is very important.

Comment: still the problem persist

Comment: If you have the same problem, it would help to give the exact error. Also post the EXACT column names and table name that you are using. Any error in spelling column names could result in the problem to occur. I had this working on my machine and I could send you the project with the DB.